# TD width - the minimum needed using CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

Consider this table:

```html
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Static length</td>
        <td>Static length</td>
        <td><div>Length varies</div></td>
        <td>Space filler</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I make the 3rd column to take the minimum width (depending on its content) and the 4th column to take the rest?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this

```
td:nth-child(3){
    background:red;
    width: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AXKUZ/)**

Comment: Works! Thanks for the demo